# Toggle div based on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following script that shows a div when a link is clicked...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.accordion ul li h1').click(function() { $(this).parent().parent().find('.ac:visible').slideToggle().parent().removeClass('active'); if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) $(this).next().slideToggle().parent().addClass('active'); });
        });
```

I also have a div on my page

```
<div id="shortinfo">short info</div>
```

How would i go about setting short info to didssapear when the link is clicked,, and reappear once its clicked again?

I tried adding

```
<h1 onclick="document.getElementById('shortinfo').style.display='none'">
```

but then i need it to reappear once its clicked again?

---

this is my new code, doesnt seem to work witht he toggle

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.accordion ul li h1').click(function() { $(this).parent().parent().find('.ac:visible').slideToggle().parent().removeClass('active'); if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) $(this).next().slideToggle().parent().addClass('active'); });
            $('#shortinfo').toggle();

        });
```

Answer (score 3):

As you are using JQuery, you can use Toggle method to display or hide the element: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

You could then do the following:

```
$('#shortinfo').toggle();
```

To integrate it with your h1 onclick, it would become:

```
<h1 onclick="$('#shortinfo').toggle()">
```

Comment: There must be something else wrong than. Toggle is the way to go here.

Comment: I know have $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.accordion ul li h1').click(function() { $(this).parent().parent().find('.ac:visible').slideToggle().parent().removeClass('active'); if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) $(this).next().slideToggle().parent().addClass('active'); });
    $('#shortinfo').toggle();

   });

Comment: Have you tried to replace your whole h1 with the latest code sample I've posted ? What version of JQuery are you using ?

Comment: ahh that h1 worked :) is there a way to have it set to display block at first, then dissapear on click?\

Comment: Make it visible via CSS then toggle() will take care of the rest: if visible it will hide it and show it otherwise.

Comment: Ive tried visibility:visible and display:block and they dont seem to work?

Comment: Do you have a test page on a server somewhere ? Also make sure parents are not hidden too.

Answer (score 1):

delete that onclick

```
$("#shortinfo").toggle();
```

Comment: I need the shortinfo to toggle display

Comment: @alicepractice: yes this does exacly you need